# how to check if my OS is not modified (is original)

Tags: rom

lets say, someone gave me an android phone ( with custom rom, lets say CM or etx). i did hard reset to erase alll data and usr apps.
but i am interested, how to know if that custom rom is not modified ( if i am afraid of spyware hard-coded into that os).

how to check if that system is clean from such custom modification, and is an original CM?

---

EDIT:
I've found interesting answer here - [How to tell if phone's ROM is original or tampered?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132368/how-to-tell-if-phones-rom-is-original-or-tampered)

Answer (score 3):

No real way to test it unless you know what you are looking for (in terms of spyware) the best solution is to flash a new CM rom from an approved site that is known to be clean.

Comment: Just make sure to do a "clean" install... Wipe all accessible partitions with TWRP/CWM recovery prior to flashing.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't been informative in your question.

Clean install with formatting or wiping of partitions is already suggested.

But, if new installation is out of options for some reason - ROM not available, can't install because you must use supplied platform or you actually want to discover whether something malicious is installed or not, you can do debugging and/or traffic sniffing from device.

I recommend Android Studio for debugging - Android device monitor.